# How to force an Apache Server to use TCP or UDP?

Tags: apache, http, tcp, udp, webserver

I've installed Apache and I want to run an Apache webserver. I understand Apache is a HTTP Server but I wonder how can I force to use TCP or UDP when connecting to it. Should I configure ports on the server side? Should I use different ways to access the server on the client side?

Comment: Why would you want to request HTTP resources over UDP?

Comment: HTTP uses TCP connection.

Comment: AFAIK Apache HTTPD does not support UDP. If you think otherwise please provide a citation: and if you can produce it, it will lead to documentation that in turn provides an answer to the 'how' question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RFC specification of HTTP does say that HTTP can be run over other protocols than TCP, but this has never been done as far as I know. If you were going to try use another protocol for some reason you would need to choose one that has flow control like TCP does. UDP is not suitable.

Apache is designed to use TCP, and any change to this would require major changes to the source code.

Comment: QUIC + HTTP/3 may change this.  QUIC reimplements much of the transport layer for the benefit of HTTP/3 and uses UDP 443.  It may be awhile until Apache gets around to implementing QUIC.